# Cannot edit the "Release Date" field for TV shows in iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows

For some reason I cannot edit the "Release Date" field in iTunes. I have been able to change it in the past, but it no longer saves changes.

[image]

I can edit the field, but changes are never saved. I'm running the latest version of iTunes on Windows (12.4.1.6). I have completely rebuilt my entire iTunes library but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "import" a TV show episode from the Windows system to your Mac, set the release date on the Mac and then copy it back to the Windows system. Not exactly a viable workaround for most but if you happen to have both platforms it may work until Apple gets their act together and starts to test their software before releasing it to their customers.

Quoted from Apple's Support Forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7567758?start=0&tstart=0

Seems like this is an issue for many and you might have to wait for a newer version.

Comment: When did Apple become Microsoft? ;___;

Comment: I purchased [MetaX](http://www.danhinsley.com/) in the meantime. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I have mapped the directories with a windows 7 machine and am able to edit the dates this looks to be an issues with Windows 10.  One of the many reasons why I down graded one of my PC to windows 7.

Comment: Maybe they've finally fixed this with the latest version of iTunes. What version are you using?